# Trying to identify a story about a child diplomat and a food that could change a creature's species

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book many years ago (pre-2003) about a kid (high school age?) who was discovered by a group of alien diplomats who needed his help. I think they crashed in his back yard.

The one part that stuck out in my mind was toward the end of the book, where the solution to some kind of conflict/problem involved the main character eating something or going through some kind of quasi-spiritual ritual that actually changed his body into that of another creature. One notable detail is that the creature he changed into had one eye that was a kind of ring around its body and gave him 360 vision. As I recall the creature was orb-ish.